# jenkins - cannot download and install plugin (multiple scm) - connection time out

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to add Multiple SCM plugin, and getting the following connection timeout error.  I am running the version 2.0.  No proxy setting.
Is there a way to get the plugin and install manually?  Thanks.

```
hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to download from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/multiple-scms/0.6/multiple-scms.hpi (redirected to: http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/multiple-scms/0.6/multiple-scms.hpi)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1153)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1650)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1848)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1624)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1105)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 8):

You can download it in your browser or use wget in your terminal:

`wget http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/multiple-scms/0.6/multiple-scms.hpi`

And then go to:
 Manager Jenkins > Plugin Manager > Advanced tab

Scroll down to the upload plugin section, click choose file to select your downloaded hpi file and press upload. After that restart Jenkins.

I was able to download the hpi plugin without a problem here, so it could be a network issue.

Answer (score 7):

Download the plugin from `http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/multiple-scms/0.6/multiple-scms.hpi` and place it inside `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins` directory and restart jenkins.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue today. Turns out the problem was the mirrors were unresponsive. Below is a web page for checking which mirrors are working, and which are not:

http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/status.html

Answer (score 0):

it could be happen for a reason that jenkins servers are down. The workaround? Nothing ... Just wait for a little bit (1-2 hours) for them to be restored